# Assigning viewModel on Controller Init?

Tags: ios, swift, mvvm, init

I am using MVVM and want to assign my viewModel to the viewController on the Controllers init. I thought I would achieve this like so:

```
class LoginViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate {

    init(loginViewModel: LoginViewModel) {
        self.loginViewModel = loginViewModel
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
```

However I get the error:

> Super.init isn't called on all paths before returning from initializer

Is this not the correct route to take? also how would I init the viewModel correctly when it requires an object to do so, but it has to perform a network request first? Init with a blank object instance?

Thanks

edit: this is what im trying now

```
initWithViewAndViewModel:(loginView: LoginView, loginViewModel: LoginViewModel) {
        super.init()
        self.loginView = loginView
        self.loginViewModel = loginViewModel
    }
```

Comment: you need to super.init in your viewcontroller init.

Comment: Call `super.init()` before assigning  loginViewModel.

Comment: thanks i tried that but i get...Must call a designated initializer of the superclass 'UIViewController'

Comment: its not super.init() ... you have to call super.init(with nib: nil,  bundle: nil) or so

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a best practice,

**Step 1:**

```
required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }
```

**Step 2:**

```
init(loginViewModel : LoginViewModel) {
        super.init(nibName: nil, bundle: nil)
        initWithModel:(loginViewModel: LoginViewModel)
    }
```

**Step 3:** implement initWithModel function

Comment: thanks, where do i need to declare initWithModel? just in the VC body? as currently it throws 'Expected declaration'

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this if it works:

```
convenience init() {
    self.init(loginViewModel: nil)
}

init(loginViewModel: LoginViewModel?) {
    self.loginViewModel = loginViewModel
    super.init(nibName: nil, bundle: nil)
}
```

Please go through this link it might help: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Initialization.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH18-XID_324